# Bad status code response from MultipartRequest

Tags: flutter, api, http

does anyone have any idea what could be wrong because I have no idea what could be causing the error?

When I'm connecting with my Rest Api where I have to put some String data and also 1 File by PostMan like in picture below:

[https://files.fm/f/vrxe9zsnu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjdij.png)

it all works how it shoud. I mean that it create new order in DB with BLOB and datas but then I'm trying doing this same on Mobile App project Idk why I'm getting respone status code 208 with message

```
{"timestamp":1647283779156,"message":"could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"}
```

I'm sending there File which I get from ImagePicker library.

```
  Future<String> multipart(File imageFile) async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
        'POST', Uri.parse(ApiHeadersInfo().createNewOrderUrl));

    request.headers.addAll({
      "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJwcEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE2NDgyODIxNjR9.ZYOo2g1iexKZynpdoIkCMbsxzHhwLDNZEIj9qUlZj2GcwqLtUTcxaBS49_xPkewg-i22eKkGNjIQAMtjw5vwIQ",
      "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    });

    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('multipartFile', imageFile.path));

    request.fields['customer'] = "newOrder.customer";
    request.fields['loadingCompanyName'] = "newOrder.loadingCompanyName";
    request.fields['loadingCity'] = "newOrder.loadingCity";
    request.fields['loadingPostcode'] = "newOrder.loadingPostcode";
    request.fields['dateOfLoading'] = "newOrder.dateOfLoading";
    request.fields['unloadingCompanyName'] = "newOrder.unloadingCompanyName";
    request.fields['unloadingPostcode'] = "newOrder.unloadingPostcode";
    request.fields['dateOfUnloading'] = "newOrder.dateOfUnloading";
    request.fields['nettoPrice'] = '11.0';
    request.fields['bruttoPrice'] = '11.0';
    request.fields['information'] = "newOrder.information";

    http.Response response = await http.Response.fromStream(await request.send());
    print("Result: ${response.statusCode}");
    print("fields: ${request.fields}");
    return response.body;
  }
```

Any ideas what is wrong here? Maybe bad http request method I just use for it ?
Have completely no idea.

Many thanks.

Comment: You absolutely need to look for the corresponding server logs.  [Edit] your post, and copy/paste the stack trace showing the server-side Hibernate exception.  PS: What framework is the server app written in?  I'm not sure why an `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` exception would return an `HTTP 208` error code.

Comment: String boot. API is uploaded on VPS server. Can u tell my how can I see the stack trace? Any option in puttY?

Comment: @paulsm4 I already found the error in stack trace. Many thanks for good advice

Comment: @vowoker: What was the error in your stack trace?